# Truffle Smart Contract Error: Invalid number of parameter

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, go-ethereum, quorum

I followed the tutorial of quorum with truffle: https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains

Now I want to migrate the SimpleStorage.sol Smart Contract to the blockchain, but I want to make it to add the "PrivateFor" parameter.

This is my Smart Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract SimpleStorage {
  uint public storedData;

  constructor(uint initVal) public {
    storedData = initVal;
  }

  function set(uint x) public {
    storedData = x;
  }

  function get() view public returns (uint retVal) {
    return storedData;
  }
}
```

This is my: 2_deploy_simplestorage.js

```
var SimpleStorage = artifacts.require("SimpleStorage");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SimpleStorage, 42, {privateFor: ["ROAZBWtSacxXQrOe3FGAqJDyJjFePR5ce4TSIzmJ0Bc="]})
};
```

But when I do truffle migrate, I get this error:

```
$ truffle migrate
⚠️  Important ⚠️
If you're using an HDWalletProvider, it must be Web3 1.0 enabled or your migration will hang.


Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      10
> Block gas limit: 3758096384


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x0a55cd010bb30247c3ae303e54be8dd13177b520af5967728cf77e07ca9efe76
- Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0x1932c48b2bF8102Ba33B4A6B545C32236e342f34
   > account:             0xed9d02e382b34818e88B88a309c7fe71E65f419d
   > balance:             1000000000
   > gas used:            245462
   > gas price:           0 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0 ETH


- Saving migration to chain.
   > Saving migration to chain.
   > Saving artifacts
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:                   0 ETH


2_deploy_simplestorage.js
=========================

   Deploying 'SimpleStorage'
   -------------------------
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"SimpleStorage" -- Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 2 expected 1!.

    at C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-deployer\src\deployment.js:364:1
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
Truffle v5.0.1 (core: 5.0.1)
Node v8.11.4
```

When I don't add the "privateFor" parameter, it works:

```
var SimpleStorage = artifacts.require("SimpleStorage");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SimpleStorage, 42)
};
```

But I need this privateFor parameter..

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved!

What I had to do is to downgrade truffle to "4.1.10" with:

```
truffle uninstall -g
```

and then

```
npm install -g truffle@4.1.10
```

Many thanks to @TS28

Answer (score 2):

Hey @BlockChainProgrammer. Thanks for guiding me on how to use the Quorum proxy. It worked.

For this error, Try to upgrade/downgrade your truffle version to v4.1.

```
$ npm install -g truffle@4.1.10
```

and change the version of solidity to 0.4.24 in your `truffle-config.js` and the `SimpleStorage.sol` and add back privateFor in your migration file.

Comment: Thanks mate. I will check it out in a few hours

Comment: Hello, so you mean in SimpleStorage.sol this: `pragma solidity ^4.1.24;` and in the truffle-config.js file this: `solc: {
      version: "4.1.24",   
    }` ? Because I get an error

Comment: That's right. In both of them you need the same version. It worked for me.

Comment: Also try to join this slack group, from the quorum website.

Comment: Hello, I get this error: `SyntaxError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.4.24+commit.e67f0147.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^4.1.24;
`

Comment: and when I try to install the solc version 4.1.24 with `npm install solc@4.1.24` I get this error: `npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for solc@4.1.24
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-24T08_12_48_682Z-debug.log
`

Comment: I also can't find this version. Are you sure you mean the version "4.1.24"?

Comment: oops sorry, I meant 0.4.24. Some typo error I guess. Hope it works.

Comment: Wich slack group do you mean? You have a link or something?

Comment: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/constellation  
The bottom of this link will have another link to their slack community.

Answer (score 0):

In this case of quorum, the

```
 {
   privateFor: ["ROAZBWtSacxXQrOe3FGAqJDyJjFePR5ce4TSIzmJ0Bc="]})
 };
```

was not defined in the contract, and at such the error, but that particular truffle compiler is compatible with Quorum features.

But For non-Quorum users like myself
The error Usually means, define a variable in your contract and not a compiler problem. Most likely a parameter not set in the constructor.

Open to corrections